# Open random page in lightbox (colorbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, lightbox, colorbox

How can I make a link open a random page from a list of pages in a colorbox lightbox based on the following code:

```
<a class="colorbox" href="page1.html"...
```

#### ==========UPDATE==========

Thanks Tomm...

I edited your code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.random").click(function() {
       var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*8+1);
       if (randomnumber == '1'){
           $(this).attr("href","anypageiwant.html");
       }
       else if....
```

However, sometimes the same random number/page is chosen more than once.  Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: So you want to do something when you click a link... where's the rest of your code?

Comment: I just put that code above to demonstrate how to open a specific page with colorbox. Instead of opening page1.html, I want it to open a page at random from a list of pages (e.g. page1/page2/page3... etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.colorbox").click(function() {
        $(this).attr("href","print"+Math.floor(Math.random()*11)+".html");
    });
});
```

Just replace the 11 with whatever number of pages you've got plus 1 (i.e. if you have page1.html to page15.html use Math.random()*16).

Comment: thanks - how do i call this function from a link? Also, what about if my pages aren't named with numbers?

Comment: 1. I've updated above code to activate when the colorbox link is clicked

Comment: 2. if your pages do not follow a certain namining convention, you will have to involve a server-side solution, e.g. PHP

Comment: thanks but is there a way to specify which links open a random page, as I have other colorbox links to specific pages that i don't want to be random

Comment: Just assign a class name to any link that should open a random page, e.g. `random` in which case you would call the function `$("a.random").click(function() { etc...` In your html markup these links would look like `a class="colorbox random" href="page1.html"...`